# How can I fix my character encoding?

Tags: html, unicode, character-encoding, char, special-characters

I have downloaded a set of web-pages and wish to simply have access to them locally (their online version has since been removed).

Loading them in chrome/Firefox, I am met with a large amount of unknown characters which render like so :

[image: Image which shows many special chars displayed as a diamond with a question mark inside.]

The HTML loads like so in Notepad++ :

[image: Image showing character encoding as xE9 and xF1 and similar.]

The image just shows one of the characters that causes an issue, however it is the same whenever an accented character is used or any special characters.

How can I fix this and make it render properly in my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply choose a different encoding from the View → Encoding menu in your browser.

The black diamonds specifically indicate that the browser is trying to interpret the page as Unicode (likely specifically UTF-8), which is apparently not the correct encoding. Try Latin-1, which will likely be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the files and insert the tag

```
<meta charset=windows-1252>
```

into the `head` part. The problem is apparently that the pages are windows-1252 encoded but treated as utf-8 encoded. It could be some other 8-bit encoding, too, so you may need to try different encodings.

Of course, it could be something more complicated, but there is not enough data to decide this.